# Entity associations mapping, ORM and Data Modelling approach for a complex task

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, associations, data-modeling

I'm working on a studio project to try to learn different approaches using Symfony2, Doctrine 2.4.7 as ORM and MySql 5.5 as DB. I've deliberately minimized my question for a better understandability and readability, if you need more details you only have to ask and apologize me if my english is not so good.

To avoid a large discussion due to the title of my question let me synthesize the problem showing a simple and common case (*but complex for me because I'm new with doctrine*).

**The Model**:

- The `User` entity (*mapped*) that stores the user's data
- The `Category` entity (*mapped*) that stores some categories associated to the User with a ManyToMany BD.
- Each User can select one or more Categories.

**The Problem**:

- User categories are near 100.
- Many Categories could have a specific associated form.
- Each form is composed by common and/or only specific fields (*from 1 to 10 fields per category*).

**The Goal**:

- Understand what's the most balanced approach for this use case (*in terms of flexibility and performances*), for create the entities and associations needed to store the data filled by the user (*some of these data I wish they were to be searchable*).

**Some Related References**:

- Doctrine2 docs
- [Serialized LOB](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serializedLOB.html)
- [Extensible Data Modelling](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/extensible-data-modeling)
- and many other threads not much relevant...

**A Possible Solution**:

- Create manually a form type for each category with inside the block of related fields (*I use this forms as services in DIC and use blocks for the fields I need to reuse on more then one category*).
- Create a `CategoryForm` entity with the properties needed to retrieve the name of the form related to the category (*useful to the form factory when I build the form*) with an association ManyToMany UD with Category and to store the serialized LOB (*the data coming from the form and related to the User*).

There is a better approach to avoid the serialization of the object in a LOB? (*maybe I'm wrong but serialized data are not searchable/indexable in mysql*)

Any other solution or reference to a readable resource is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I will try to answer the question with a simple guess: the category is something shared beetween several users (since you got the many to many).

So, if you want the User's form to be able to set (add/delete or update) Categories assiated to the user, then you should just have acollection of entity widgets related to the Category.

Why do I say that ?

Since your categories are linked to several users, the way you want to treat the relation beetween Categories and Users will cause any update on existing Category from a User's form to be propagated to other Users.
This means that Categories should be created/updated by a single form (modulo your needs). You can then link the Category to the User from User's form.

As far as the number of form of Categories is concerned, there are several parameters to handle:

- Are all the Categories validated the same way (to know if you simply need to hide widgets to make the validation work) ?
- Do you have a large amount of different types of Categories ?
- If yes, are always composed the same way for a given type ?

Give further details if I'm wrong in my initial guess ;)

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer. ASAP I'll add a bit of code to my question so we can discuss on it basing on a real example.

Comment: Thanks to your reply and after some hours I realized that my question needs to be splitted in more parts (and explained more clearly) also due to the vastity of the argument, so I'll update this ASAP (I can't close it due to the answer).